# How extensive was the slighting of castles in the English Civil War?

Tags: england, 17th-century, english-civil-war, castles

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slighting) states

> During the English Civil War many castles and fortified houses were
>   slighted by the Parliamentarians to stop them being used by the
>   Royalists. Most of the destruction was in Wales, the Midlands, and
>   Yorkshire e.g. Pontefract Castle. The coastal fortifications were
>   spared by the Commonwealth, as they might have been useful for
>   hindering a Royalist or foreign invasion.

I haven't been able to find how many *castles and fortified houses* were affected.

Answer (score 8):

On 20 October 1645, Parliament resolved that the Committee of Both Kingdoms should consider which castles and fortifications were to be slighted. Through 1646 and beyond, Parliament passed a series of resolutions to slight castles. I'm not sure that a central list exists but you can probably compile one easily if you search for "slighted" in the [Journal of the House of Commons](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aRRDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA526&lpg=PA526#v=onepage&q&f=false). There's a useful overview (but no list) on pages 56-57 of [English Civil War Fortifications 1642-51 by Peter Harrington, Donato Spedaliere](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=V6p-ngom89QC&pg=PA56).

Answer (score 2):

Dr Lila Rakoczy wrote a thesis on the topic. You can read it for free: http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/11092/

I think the number of castles slighted was over 100 (can't remember exactly).

Comment: You might want to expand the answer to include the key facts from the thesis as links are subject to 'rot'.